# How can I retrieve the number of zero entries from a certain number of rows for a single from a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset

If I was to have a dataset with one column and and multiple rows each with different values, how could I count the number of zero entries for a certain number of rows

Example: I have 10,000 rows and thus 10,000 values but I want the number of zero entries of the first 50 values. How could I store this in a variable for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a logical condition and get the sum based on the first 50 elements

```
v1 <- sum(df1[[1]][1:50] == 0)
```

Here, the column index used  is 1 as the first column.  If it different, change the index

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `table` to calculate the frequency of each values and display only the output obtained for 0:

```r
df <- data.frame(X = sample(0:20,100, replace = TRUE))

> table(df[1:50,])["0"]
0 
1
```